# Is my svn hosting service automatically removing old committed versions of my code?

Tags: svn

My subversion project on a svn hosting service is almost full (there is not anymore free space).

I was wondering if the repository is automatically removing old versions (commitments) in order to free space for the new ones. Or does it depends on the provider ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure Repository won't remove the old versions.

Comment: Yes you can. Please follow http://robmayhew.com/delete-parts-of-subversion-history/

Comment: But if your main concern is to create more free space you should check your tmp file usage and remove those. or remove unwanted or unused software installed.

Comment: Ok thanks, one last question: if I delete a file (rm command in unix), and then I create it again, do I delete its previous versions or it is the same ? thanks